# How to select an item in a comma separated list field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a table named `product`, where in the `category` field I have inserted around 5 to 6 categories.

For example `2,3,4,5,12` just like that.

But when I use this query it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE category in '3' 

SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `category` LIKE '%3%'
```

can anyone help to fix it

Comment: Could you provide sample data for your table `product` and specify what exactly you want to extract with your query?

Comment: is `2,3,4,5,12` in a single cell or on different row?

Comment: Before fixing this, I suggest that you normalize your database schema. Your database schema violates [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), especially "Every row-and-column intersection contains exactly one value from the applicable domain (and nothing else)."

Comment: Yes, this is breaking even `1NF`. If `category` is a multi-valued attribute i.e. you are keeping all categories of a product in a single column, then you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3',category);
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

If you don't have find_in_set this code would be equivalent:

```
SELECT * FROM product 
WHERE category = '3' or category LIKE '%,3,%' 
      or category LIKE '3,%' or category LIKE '%,3';
```

Otherwise you will get a false positive for 3 on `'13, 23, 40'`.

**Warning**
Do note however that it's very bad practise to put a CSV list in a field.
You'll get much better performance by extracting the list out of the field and putting it in another table in a 1-to-N relation.

Comment: `or category LIKE '%,3,%' category LIKE '%,3' or category LIKE '3,%'` Otherwise it would give false positives for 30, 35, 320, etc: `2,30,45`

Comment: @ypercube fixed, anyway that's why `find_in_set` is better.

Comment: Yes, `FIND_IN_SET()` is the way to solve such query, if the db can't be normalized.

Answer (score 2):

the best practice would be to create another table!

i.e.:
product_categories
int productid
int category

```
SELECT * FROM product p 
INNER JOIN product_categories pc ON pc.productid = p.productid 
WHERE pc.category = '3'
```

with the way you want to implement it, you would also have a problem when a category '13' is available, but you want to have '3'

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say it but you should redesign your database.
Using a single field to store multiple connections will always be a pain in the butt.

It is much easier to create an additional table that stores the relations.

Comment: i don't have any other option will any one suggest a good solution for it

Answer (score 1):

The IN statement wont work because you are asking for the category to be an exact match of "3" when it is in fact "2,3,4,5,12". I think it should also be in round brackets.

As user737767 said you should really [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database so you have a table of categories, a table of products and another table to show which categories each product belongs to.

Your LIKE statement is also a bad idea because searching for "3" will also bring back results like "23"